# Cant create file name with time stamp

Tags: r

I have a file that I would to write away in a certain dir. Therefore I have the following code:

```
 function <- {

   file_path_new <- file.path("C:", "Users", "MavanderPeet", "Documents", "data")
   setwd(file_path_new)

  now <- Sys.time()
  file_name <- paste0(now, "data_set.csv")
  write.csv(data_frame, file_name)
  # write.csv(data_frame, "file.csv") #for checking purposes

 }
```

The part where I want to create a name with timestamp does not seem to work however... When I uncomment the line

```
 write.csv(data_frame, "file.csv")
```

Everything works fine. So I guess it should be a syntax error....

Any thoughts??

Comment: if it's syntax, could this help? `now2 <- gsub(':|-', '_', now)`

Comment: you should print the value of file_name, this would be an unusual filename at the least (and possibly not allowed on windows; can't check that).  Try paste0(format(Sys.time(), format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "xxxx.csv") to get a better formatted date.  Change the format string to suit your tastes.

Answer (score 15):

The colon (`:`)  is not allowed in Windows file names ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#naming_conventions)).

Use a different format:

`paste0(format(now, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"), "data_set.csv")`

Answer (score 2):

In the [answer by @Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31004556/13865476), `now` needs parenthesis:

```r
paste0(format(now(), "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_"), "data_set.csv")
```

Comment: I don't think so: `now` is not a function. It's defined as `now <- Sys.time()` in OP's code.

Comment: @fcdt You're right - I had lubridate loaded for something else and there is a now() function for it.